# Androidplot StackedBar chart Range labels

Tags: android, charts, androidplot, stackedbarseries

I have 3 data series on a StackedBar Chart with AndroidPlot. 
For example:

```
Number[] serie1 = new Number[]{1,4,2,5,3};
Number[] serie2 = new Number[]{3,2,8,2,0};
Number[] serie3 = new Number[]{7,1,12,8,2};
```

In my chart, I have 3 ticks. And for example the values it takes to shown in the label are from series1 min 1 to series1 max 5 that it's the max from serie1. Indeed a total imaginary range will be

```
Number[] imaginaryTotal = new Number[11,7,22,15,5}; // sum of all series index
```

So the labels I must show will be from min 5 to max 15

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you currently have and something that illustrates how you want it to look?  Like Mirakels, I'm not able to visualize your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the problem (maybe you can add some pictures on what you get and what you expect).
But maybe your issues can be solved by using the setRangeBoundaries() method?